# Toy almost everywhere flat metric

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, relativity

I was looking into this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0207057) from 2003 by Krasnikov - “The quantum inequalities do not forbid spacetime shortcuts” - and apart from the fact that I find it very scetchy without many details and hard to follow - because I feel it is unstructured and not quite clear what follows from what - I just have a question about a specific metric he introduces in the beginning i.e. which is depicted in FIG1 and I state here for the 2 dimensional case. I however find his notation somewhat unintuitively so maybe I understand something wrong. Anyway...
$$
{\rm d}s^2 = {\rm d}t^2 - {\rm d}r^2 - R^2(r) {\rm d}\phi^2
$$
where
$$
R(r)=\begin{cases} r \qquad D_a + \delta < r \\ ? \qquad D_a<r<D_a+\delta \\ r-(D_a-d) \qquad D_a-d<r<D_a \\ 0 \qquad r<D_a-d\end{cases}
$$
that's how I at least read it. In the slice $D_a < r < D_a + \delta$ it is not specified is that right? And for $r<D_a - d$ it vanishes?

He then argues that null cones are "more open" inside the cylinder.
How is that? Null cones are
$${\rm d}s^2 = 0$$
that is for the choice $\phi={\rm const}$ these are the lines $t=\pm r$ which are just the flat null cones also inside. What am I missing here?

Comment: *that's how I at least read it*. You read it wrong. $r\ge D_a - d$ (in the paper) is a domain specification for a variable $r$ …

Comment: Which then means? $r-(D_a-d) \geq 0$ and what about $r-(D_a-d)<0$? So you are saying this doesn't exist?

Comment: I mean if $r-(D_a-d)<0$ doesn't exist how can he talk about inside the cylinder?

Comment: But $D_a<r<D_a+\delta$ is unspecified as he says "flat except in a thin annulus"? But what about the "more open" ? For constant $\phi$ the region $D_a-d < r < D_a$ still has the same null cones.

Comment: What is EC, energy condition; of which the only one he discusses is the WEC? But on page 3 he writes: "The null cones in Z (or in Zb see figure 1c) can be tilted so much (with the metric remaining flat) that a future-directed null vector is directed in the sense of decreasing t [2] (which, being again a coordinate effect, has no direct connection with causality — the spacetime is globally hyperbolic)." And FIG1 specifically points towards the interior so $r<D_a-d$?

Comment: Is that not correct?

Comment: I'm just wondering what to do with the case $r<D_a-d$. Is it left untouched as in the Schwarzschild case where the SS coordinates don't make sense for the inner part? Why should I draw lightcones other than $\phi={\rm const}$? I'm not sure how that matters? I mean in flat minkowsi spacetime all the lightcones are also just $t=\pm \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ as the ones above? Also generally how do you want to solve $$1=\left(\frac{{\rm d}r}{{\rm d}t}\right)^2 + R^2(r)\left(\frac{{\rm d}\phi}{{\rm d}t}\right)^2 \, ?$$

Comment: Or do you mean by solving the geodesic equation? But still that would give me lines of constant $\phi$ or constant $r$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OP's notation the actual definition of function $R(r)$ should be
$$R(r)=\begin{cases} r  &r\ge D_a + \delta, \\ ? & D_a<r<D_a+\delta , \\ r-(D_a-d) & D_a-d\le r \le D_a. \end{cases}$$
In other words no last branch, because radial variable $r$ is *defined* only on the half-line $r\ge D_a -d$. At $r=D_a-d$ there is a coordinate singularity but it is easy to see that it is the same coordinate singularity that is at z-axis of a usual cylindrical coordinates of the 3D flat space.

So the manifold of 2+1 “shortcut” example consists of three parts, glued along their boundaries:

1. Flat interior cylinder of the radius $d$. It we introduce auxiliary radial variable $\rho= r-(D_a - d)$ the metric in this region takes the form
   $$
   ds^2=dt^2-d\rho^2-\rho^2 d\phi^2,\qquad 0\le \rho \le d,
   $$
   in other words, Minkowski metric inside the timelike cylinder.
2. *Curved* region.   Its spacelike section is an aunnulus $D_a<r<D_a+\delta $. The function $R(r)$ for this region, though not defined explicitly must be chosen to smoothly interpolate between the boundary values of $d$ and $D_a+\delta$. So, while the radial variable changes by $\delta$ the circumference of circles $r=\rm const$ varies from  $2\pi d$ for the inner circle to $2\pi (D_a+\delta)$ for the outer circle.
3. The outer region is a flat Minkowski spacetime outside the timelike cylinder given by $r\ge D_a + \delta $.

To visualize the spacetime one could draw the lightcones on the crossection by the plane passing through the $t$-axis. For visualization we could make of two choices:

- We could isometrically embed both flat regions in the diagram.  This means that the curved region would be stretched along the radial direction. This is illustrated by the following image:

[image: Stretched annulus]

Curved (shaded) region is stretched but its proper radial thickness is only $\delta$. Therefore the slant of null geodesics in it is small.

- Alternatively, we could keep the radial thickness of the curved region. This means that the interior region must be stretched along the spatial direction:

[image: Stretched inner region]

This visualization would indeed make the lightcones of the interior region more “open” as the slant of null geodesic is smaller due to the stretching. But of course, this is only effect of this particular visualization choice of coordinates.

Comment: First of all thanks very much! I know you will tell me it is because of the stretching, but I still don't think the null-line for $r>D_a+\delta$ has a different slant than for $r<D_a$. After all in each region the null-cones are of the form $t=\pm (r-r_0)$. And with $d$ coordinate you actually want to emphasize "length" and not coordinate, or? If I would have drawn the figure I would have started at $r=D_a-d$ and there was nothing for $r<D_a-d$, but I see that has its downside...

Comment: @Diger: $r=D_a-d$ is an axis of symmetry. It is the center of the cylinder. And in the second plot the $\delta r$ of the interior region is mapped onto $2 \delta x $ of the diagram, while for the outside $\delta r $ corresponds to $\delta x $. The stretching coefficient of spatial dimension is position dependent, while time coordinate is the same across all region.

Comment: Sorry, but now you again introduce new variables...What is $\delta r$ and $\delta x$? Do you mean $\delta t$? Maybe you mean $\delta x$ is mapped on $\delta t=\delta x/2$ in the inner part and on $\delta t=\delta x$ outside?

Comment: x and t are horizontal and vertical axis of the plot. r is the variable from the paper. If you don't like $\delta x $ you can read it as $dx$. The stretching applies to *changes* of coordinates and not to their absolute values.

Comment: Maybe I mixed that up. So $x$ and $r$ are indeed not the same in the interior region? The factor 2 is for this specific case you plotted or general? What values did you use ($d,D_a,\delta,...$)?

Comment: Factor 2 is just for the specific plot. $x$ in the outside regions is just a cartesian coordinate but for the inside crossection its continuation is ambiguous (two plots are examples). For the plots $d=4$, $D_a=8$, $\delta=0.5$ in grid units of graphic editor.